# How to update the constant height constraint of a UIView with IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to change the height of my menu view so that it opens, but when I add the IBOutlet of the NSLayoutConstraint it keeps crashing my app with the same error code. I Triple checked that the Outlet is correctly connected so that's not the problem. Am I missing something or is this updated within the new Xcode as all other questions are from at least 5 years ago.

thanks!

error message:

> Thread 1: "[<UIViewController 0x7f8fe2705330> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key menuHeightConstraint."

Relevant code:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: IBOutlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var menuHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!
    
    
    // MARK: Variables
    
    var menuIsOpen = false
    
    // MARK: IBaction functions
    
    @IBAction func openMenu() {
        menuIsOpen.toggle()
        menuHeightConstraint.constant = menuIsOpen ? 180 : 55
        
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 1,
            delay: 0,
            options: .curveEaseIn,
            animations: { self.menuView.layoutIfNeeded() },
            completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

[IBOutlet in storryboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvxAJ.png)
[---- Hierarchy in storyboard ----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjBRV.png)

Comment: `UIViewController` in the exception message tells you that you haven't set the custom class for your scene; It is creating a `UIViewController` instance, not a `HomeViewController` instance, so the outlet isn't there

Comment: Well I'm directly from storyboard connecting the constraint to the NSLayoutConstraint inside the ViewController of the visible screen. Isn't this the right way? since I normally do it this way... I added another picture with the hierarchy of my storyboard

Comment: How did you create the view controller instance?  All I can tell you is that the exception says you have an instance of `UIViewController`, not an instance of `HomeViewController`.  Check you aren't getting a warning in the console about an unknown view controller class.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if your `menuView` outlet is hooked up, but from the screenshot you included it seems it isn't.  In that case it'd be crashing because `menuView` will be nil when you try to call `self.menuView.layoutIfNeeded()`. Either way, you should be calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` instead anyway.

Comment: Yeah I saw that when I took the screenshot so I connected it but still crashes with same error...

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be an Xcode error, I restarted the project the next day and it worked fine. So if you want to edit a constraint with animation, you can do it as seen above :-)